# TraceListener headers and footers

Tags: .net, logging, tracelistener, tracesource

When writing a custom TraceListener how can I force the writeheader, the data/messsage, and the writefooter to be one discreet record?  Specifically the custom tracelisteners in question  write to a non file based source, such as database or event stream.   I need to either have the writeHeader, writefooter base methods in TraceListener be ignored or somehow packaged into a single write event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is a good article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/09/21/472021.aspx) on how custom `TraceListener`s work, which also explains when and wh `WriteHeader` and `WriteFooter` are called.  The trick to avoiding `WriteHeader` and `WriteFooter` is apparently to override the [TraceData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.tracedata.aspx) and/or [TraceEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.traceevent.aspx) calls.

There is also some discussion of this issue in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826211/how-does-system-tracelistener-prepend-message-with-process-name).

Finally, I would encourage you to take a look at [Ukadc.Diagnostics](http://ukadcdiagnostics.codeplex.com/) it is a pretty cool library for extending `System.Diagnostics` and provides, among other features, a nice way to achieve some log4net/NLog-like output formatting.  There is a little bit of discussion about this library in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062277/net-how-to-suppress-tracesource-header-sourcename-traceeventtype-id).

Good luck!

Comment: Great article. Worth reading alone for the section on GetSupportedAttributes.